# How can I force update of the UI in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, dispatcher

Alright, let me try to explain.

I have an application where I can trigger some sort of scan process. This scan process launches (just a number) 10 background workers which do something. After (again, just a number) 5 seconds I would like to

- Kill all the background workers (I'm using CancelAsync for that)
- Do some calculation with the data I got from all of them
- Update the UI so the data is displayed AND enable some buttons (these buttons are bound through a `ViewModel` Command called `PerformUpdateCommand` and they have a `CanExecute` property of `IsPerformUpdateAllowed`. The `IsPerformUpdateAllowed` dependency property is set when my tasks finish.

What I thought I would do:

- After triggering the Background Workers, start a dispatcher timer with a 5 second interval.
- When the `DispatcherTimer` "ticks" I calculate the data and set the property `IsPerformUpdateAllowed` to either true or false.

This basically works as expected (the UI stays responsive, ...) with just a minor hickup: The UI is not being updated (the button is not enabled). As soon as I put the window into the background and back into the foreground, the command is enabled, also the `IsPerformUpdateAllowed` property is set to true. Also, when I press the button (in disabled state) after pressing it, it will be enabled.

So, although I set the dependency property correctly, the UI does not react to this change.

Anybody knows why? Interestingly, I also set some text in the UI into a label - this text is updated correctly. It's just that the property which tells the command `CanExecute` does not trigger a UI update.

Code for the initialization of the timer.

```
        _scanTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _scanTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3);
        _scanTimer.Tick += delegate
        {
            // After the timer has elapsed (some time passed), cancel all scans and update the result
            _scanTimer.Stop();
            UpdateScanResults();
            CancelNormalScans(false);
        };
        _scanTimer.Start();
```

Code how the Command is bound to the WPF element (the button is actually a Hyperlink):

```
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ReadSettingsCommand}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Loc}, Path=Labels.ReadSettings}"></TextBlock>
                </Hyperlink>
            </Label>
```

Here is the code for the Command

```
    public RelayCommand ReadSettingsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _readSettingsCommand
                ?? (_readSettingsCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteReadSettings, () => IsScannedDeviceAvailable && !IsUpdateInProgress));
        }
    }
```

The code is actually dependent on two dependency properties IsScannedDeviceAvailable AND NOT IsUpdateInProgress. Both are dependency properties.

UPDATE: I just read that the binding to the CanExecute property is just one time. If you want it to revalidate you need to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged on the command. This works, but it is somewhat cumbersome, since now I need to call it manually every time one of the two properties change. Actually I wanted that to be handled automatically. Any ideas on how this can be done more easily? Isn't there some method to have kind of a one-way binding between CanExecute and the property?

Comment: What is your IsPerformUpdateAllowed DependencyProperty on?

Comment: Your ICommands aren't raising the CanExercuteChanged event.

Comment: @Aron: Is there a better way than to manually call RaiseCanExecuteChanged?

Comment: @TomL. that is the best way. for view model operations it can be assumed that you know when the application is ready for command input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either on your VM call RaiseCanExecuteChanged whenever IsScannedDeviceAvailable/IsUpdateInProgress is set. OR My personal favorite create your own implementation of `ICommand` since its pretty simple anyway.

```
public class FooCommand : ICommand
{
    private bool _canExecute;
    private Action _delegate;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public new bool CanExecute
    {
        get
        {
            return _canExecute;
        }
        set
        {
            _canExecute = value;
            if(CanExecuteChanged != null)
                CanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _delegate();
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute()
    {
        return CanExecute;
    }

    public FooCommand(Action action)
    {
        _delegate = action;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work. Yet, I actually wanted to code the whole thing the other way around. Once all conditions for a command are fulfilled, it should get enabled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are triggering a change in a `Command.CanExecute()` based on a property, you can also call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` to force the `CanExecute()` to be re-evaluated.

Comment: That wouldn't be very efficient since it will have to evaluate all the commands.